# Jqgrid representation of a sub object

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I have a controller method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
 public UserList saveUser(@RequestBody UserList userList) {
 //some operation
}
```

The structure of the object is given below

```
  public class UserList {
  private List<User> userList;
  //getters and setters

 }
  Public class User{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private Role role;
  // getters and setters
   }

  Public class Role{
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private String description;
    //getters and setters
  }
```

the controller method expects the json in form of

```
   {"userList":[{"id":"1","name":"xyz",  
    role:{"id":"1","name":"admin","description":"administrator"}}]}
```

how can i define a jqgrid such a way that submit should hit the mentioned controller, ie we need to get the json of form as above .**please mention the 'colModel'** ,
while i am using the dot operator like **{name:'role.description',index:'role.description', width:55}**  is giving the null object of Role inside User object.